# How do you attach a constructor function method to an element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to learn about OOP JavaScript. I'm trying to create a constructor function that adjusts the height of an element that exists in the HTML.

In my example, I have a div called `myDiv` - I want to be able to create a constructor function and attach it to any element I want. I know you can do this with jQuery, by creating a custom function, and attaching it to jQuery's `$.fn` - but I want to approach it with just vanilla JS.

```
<div class="myDiv"></div>

.myDiv {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  transition: height 1s;
}

function ChangeHeight() {
  this.expand = function() {
   return $(this).css('height', '400px');
  }
  this.collapse = function() {
   return $(this).css('height', '0px');
  }
  console.log($(this).height());
}

var myDiv = $('.myDiv');

myDiv = new ChangeHeight();
div.collapse();
console.log('log: ' + myDiv);
```

I'm just testing a few things out, but I don't think I'm approaching it the right way.

Comment: `var myDiv = $('.myDiv');` and on the next line `myDiv = new ChangeHeight();`??? A typo in the post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Class will provide the functionality you want:

```js
class ChangeHeight {
  constructor(el) {
    this.el = el;
    console.log($(el).height());
  }

  expand() {
    $(this.el).css('height', '400px');
  }

  collapse() {
    $(this.el).css('height', '0px');
  }
}

var myDiv = $('.myDiv');

myDiv = new ChangeHeight(myDiv);
myDiv.collapse();
```

```css
.myDiv {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  transition: height 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for getting back to me. That worked! - I have a question, though. You pass the element to the constructor as an argument. which I get. However, you then override the "myDiv" variable by saying its a new instance of "changeHeight" - so, wouldn't the reference to the element "myDiv" be overridden and forgotten?

Comment: yes, if you want the original `myDiv` then use a different variable name for the instance of `ChangeHeight`. Alternatively, if you don't need the reference to the element, you can just pass the selector string to the class constructor (as, say, `selector`) and use `this.el = $(selector)` instead

Answer (score -1):

Constructor Function is a Function with parameters. The body of the constructor is the body of the function itself.

```
function Vehicle(tyre, body) {
    this.tyre = tyre;
    let newbody = body + ' (new)';
    this.body = newbody;
    this.view = () => {
        console.log('tyre: ', this.tyre);
        console.log('body: ', this.body);
    }
}

let car = new Vehicle(4, 'toyota');

car.view();
```

Hope I helped someone.

Comment: "You must research before putting your question. Anyways." Likewise, it would be a good habit to always describe your answer's code and how it solves OP's problem/answers their question. Walls of code typically aren't very constructive.

Comment: Thank you, will do next time.

Comment: Why not edit this answer and do it _this_ time to make it good enough to upvote?